# Modifying a particular line using sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

My text file contains:

```
/**
 *
**/
```

I want to replace the second line with `text.txt` so that it looks something like:

```
/**
 * text.txt
**/
```

I tried the following sed command but it rendered the text file empty.

```
sed -n 2p -i -e "/^ \*/ s/ \*/ \* text.txt/" example.txt
```

Please let me know what I need to do to get the desired result.

Comment: To you want to add the *string* `text.txt` or to you want to add the *contents* of that file?

Comment: Is it always the second line of the file which need to be modfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i -e "2s/$/ test.txt/" example.txt
```

if you want to do the replacement in line 2, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

To add that to the line after `/**`

```
sed '/^\/\*\*/ {n; s/$/ text.txt/;}' example.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the second line (independently on its content), use

```
 sed -i -e '2c\ * test.txt' example.txt
```

`2` addresses the second line, `c\` replaces it with the rest of the argument
(`\` is needed otherwise the space is omitted).